# Uri and storage paths differ - Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, uri, android-external-storage, start-activity

Where a downloaded file is stored and where Uri goes to pick it up are not the same.

```
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(Query.filePathh);
Console.WriteLine("Downloaded file PATH: " + Query.filePathh);

Intent open = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
open.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
open.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;


Android.Net.Uri fileUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, "com.companyname.Login.provider", file).NormalizeScheme();
Console.WriteLine("File uri: " + fileUri.Path);
open.SetDataAndType(fileUri, "*/*");

Intent intentC = Intent.CreateChooser(open, "Open With");
intentC.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);

intentC.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intentC);
```

We get pop-up that asked how to open a file, but when the application tries to open it, it crashes with an error that the file path does not exist.

While debugging we tried to see file locations on where the file is downloaded and what Uri is calling and we get:

For storage_path: 

storage/emulated/0/Download/How_to_initialize_your_Xamarin_app_to_use_AppConnect_C#_APIs.pdf

For Uri path:

/external/Download/How_to_initialize_your_Xamarin_app_to_use_AppConnect_C#_APIs.pdf

We can open the file normally if we go to Download folder in our Emulator.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: You should look at Uri.toString(). Not at Uri.getPath(). Then you will see the content scheme.

Comment: @blackapps For External Storage, the uri like /storage/emulated/0/Download, don't see like /external/Download, you can take a look:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows

Comment: @ Cherry Bu - MSFT
We are using External Storage but when doing:
Android.Net.Uri fileUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, "com.companyname.Login.provider", file);
We get the 'wrong' path to the file, the one without:
storage/emulated/0/Download
It seems like the Uri conversion changes storage/smulated/0 with external and that's why external apps cannot open saved files

Comment: You should use fileUri.toString(). Not fileUri.getPath(). Please give/tell both values.